# How do I configure AVPlayer to play a video that was recorded at 120fps?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a simple app that records video at 120fps, saves it to the documents directory, and then uses an instance of AVPlayer to play it back.

If I set the playback rate to 1.0 (for the AVPlayer instance), the playback is a bit choppy (probably more along the lines of 60fps). However, if I interrupt the playback by pressing the "play" button (which then sets the playback rate to 1.0 again!), it plays back very smoothly.

For instance, this is what occurs when the user presses the play button (and yes, I observe the 'status' property of AVPlayer before allowing the user to play the video):

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.videoPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self.videoPlayer setRate:1];
    self.videoPlayer.volume = 1;
}
```

And this is my simple player-setup code:

```
- (void)setUpAVPlayer
{
    self.videoURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:self.videoURL.path];
    self.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.videoURL];

    [self.previewLayer setPlayer:self.videoPlayer];

    // observe player status
    [self.videoPlayer addObserver:self
                       forKeyPath:@"status"
                          options:0
                          context:nil];
}
```

There really is nothing unusual about what I'm doing. It plays back video fine. It's only the case where the video was recorded at 120fps that there is a playback issue.

(Also, this is running on my iPhone5s since it is the only device that supports 120fps.)

Comment: Were you able to get it solved?